Error while installing node_modules in React js
I just cloned a React application that doesn't have node_modules on it. I try to install with command npm install but unable to do it. Following error occurs when installing the npm.
I have also tried npm i --force.The project clone has packages which is not updated for so long.
npm ERR! In file included from ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_stack.h:47:
npm ERR! In file included from ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/call_combiner.h:30:
npm ERR! ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gprpp/ref_counted.h:83:59: warning: unused parameter 'trace_flag' [-Wunused-parameter]
npm ERR!   constexpr explicit RefCount(Value init = 1, TraceFlagT* trace_flag = nullptr)
npm ERR!                                                           ^
npm ERR! ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gprpp/ref_counted.h:103:33: warning: unused parameter 'location' [-Wunused-parameter]
npm ERR!   void Ref(const DebugLocation& location, const char* reason, Value n = 1) {
npm ERR!                                 ^
npm ERR! ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gprpp/ref_counted.h:103:55: warning: unused parameter 'reason' [-Wunused-parameter]
npm ERR!   void Ref(const DebugLocation& location, const char* reason, Value n = 1) {
npm ERR!                                                       ^
npm ERR! ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gprpp/ref_counted.h:129:40: warning: unused parameter 'location' [-Wunused-parameter]
npm ERR!   void RefNonZero(const DebugLocation& location, const char* reason) {
npm ERR!                                        ^
npm ERR! ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gprpp/ref_counted.h:129:62: warning: unused parameter 'reason' [-Wunused-parameter]
npm ERR!   void RefNonZero(const DebugLocation& location, const char* reason) {
npm ERR!                                                              ^
npm ERR! ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gprpp/ref_counted.h:153:42: warning: unused parameter 'location' [-Wunused-parameter]
npm ERR!   bool RefIfNonZero(const DebugLocation& location, const char* reason) {
npm ERR!                                          ^
npm ERR! ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gprpp/ref_counted.h:153:64: warning: unused parameter 'reason' [-Wunused-parameter]
npm ERR!   bool RefIfNonZero(const DebugLocation& location, const char* reason) {
npm ERR!                                                                ^
npm ERR! ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gprpp/ref_counted.h:184:35: warning: unused parameter 'location' [-Wunused-parameter]
npm ERR!   bool Unref(const DebugLocation& location, const char* reason) {
npm ERR!                                   ^
npm ERR! ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/gprpp/ref_counted.h:184:57: warning: unused parameter 'reason' [-Wunused-parameter]
npm ERR!   bool Unref(const DebugLocation& location, const char* reason) {


Is it a public repository, can you check the package.json file to view the package versions

Looks like it's trying to natively compile a C dependency. This is something you'd need to raise with the project maintainers

We're missing the start of this error

This error occurs when building the grpc package, which has been deprecated in part because of compatibility issues with the build. You should encourage whichever package depends on it to switch to @grpc/grpc-js, the recommended replacement.

Kindly include the following command
npm cache clean --force

then, Delete package-lock.json or yarn.lock: and add below cmd
npm install


I have followed your steps
Its showing "npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v20.11.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.0.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! Node-gyp failed to build your package.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! Try to update npm and/or node-gyp and if it does not help file an issue with the package author."
But i dont want to update npm .is there any solution.
